# Binary functions as a map into a set of functions

Tags: functions, reference-request, terminology, computer-science

Let F be a set of functions of the form $f:B\to C$ such that $f(b)=c$ for $b\in B$ and  $c\in C$.

Consider $g:A\to F$ such that $g(a)= f$ for $a\in A$ and $f\in F$.

Then, $g(a)(b)=c$

There is apparently a formal sense in which the above construction is equivalent to a binary function from $A\times B$ to $C$. I vaguely remember(?) that the name of this idea comes from computer science but am unable to find it online. I do also recall an nLab article discussing something similar in categorical terms.

I am hoping to find the terminology for shifting between these two constructions. Thoughts on how to make precise the notion that the above two constructions, which intuitively convey the same information, are equivalent would be appreciated but are not required. If I knew the appropriate terminology I am confident I could learn more online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category theory terminology you are looking for is an “exponential object”. Given objects $A$ and $B$, an exponential object $A^B$, which in the category of sets is the set of functions from $B$ to $A$, is an object $A^B$ together with a natural isomorphism $Hom(C, A^B) \cong Hom(C \times B, A)$ (natural in $C$). The map $A^B \times B \to A$ which corresponds under this isomorphism to the identity map $A^B \to A^B$ is known as the evaluation map (taking $C = A^B$); the exponential can be described purely in terms of the evaluation map rather than the natural isomorphism.

In computer science, this concept is known as “currying” (named after Haskell Curry, who is also the namesake of the programming language Haskell). Currying is taking a function $C \times B \to A$ and producing a function $C \to A^B$; uncurrying is the inverse operation.

Comment: "Currying" is the term I was looking for. I chose this answer because of the helpful reference to exponential objects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the terms you’re looking for here are [“Currying” and “Uncurrying.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)